# \rput not working in TexShop 3.51

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

`\rput` is not working, I change the coordinates but "(a)" does not move at all. Here the code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.90\columnwidth]{figure.pdf}
\rput[tr](-0.94\columnwidth,0.88\columnwidth){(a)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you run the document with `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex`

Comment: The options I have are: Plain Tex, Latex, BibTex, MakeIndex, MetaPost, ConText, ConText (LuaTex), LuLaTex, nv-metafun, nv-metapost, pdflatexmk, sepdflatexmk, XeLaTex and XeTex. I always choose Latex, which gives a pdf as an output. But actually, I just tried to do it with XeLaTex and rput works. What am I suppose to choose to run the tex file?

Comment: Then use `xelatex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSTricks cannot be used directly with `pdflatex`. Run instead `xelatex`.